# Openssl error message on install log when installing ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: ruby, openssl, installation, rvm, osx-snow-leopard

Hi I am trying to install ruby via rvm using the following code:

`CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-openssh-dir=$rvm_path/usr`

but I am getting errors on the (installation) make.log file:

> In file included from openssl_missing.c:22:
>   450 openssl_missing.h:71: error: conflicting types for ‘HMAC_CTX_copy’
>
> 451 /Users/Sebastian/.rvm/usr/include/openssl/hmac.h:102: error: previous declaration of ‘HMAC_CTX_copy’ was here
>
> 452 openssl_missing.h:95: error: conflicting types for ‘EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy’
>
> 453 /Users/Sebastian/.rvm/usr/include/openssl/evp.h:503: error: previous declaration of ‘EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy’ was here
>
> 454 openssl_missing.c:27: error: conflicting types for ‘HMAC_CTX_copy’
>
> 455 /Users/Sebastian/.rvm/usr/include/openssl/hmac.h:102: error: previous declaration of ‘HMAC_CTX_copy’ was here
>
> 456 openssl_missing.c:122: error: conflicting types for ‘EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy’
>
> 457 /Users/Sebastian/.rvm/usr/include/openssl/evp.h:503: error: previous declaration of ‘EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy’ was here
>
> 458 make[2]: [openssl_missing.o] Error 1
>
> 459 make[1]: [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
>
> 460 make: [build-ext] Error 2

I've read that this could be related to macports installation but I made sure I removed everything related to it.

On the other hand, there is a openssl file in another location at **/usr/bin/**. I am not sure if this can be causing conflicts but I didn't dare to delete it.

I'd appreciate your help on this.

Thank you

Comment: Same problem here, not any of the workaround worked for me.. only a downgrade `rvm` made the trick: `rvm get 1.10.0`

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar problem after installing rvm's openssl pkg to testdrive ruby 2.0.0.

After some fiddling, the following solved it for me:

- Get your rvm up to date:

  `$ rvm get head`
- Remove your manually installed packages:

  `$ rvm pkg remove`
- Get the requirements straight:

  `$ rvm requirements run`

  Here I got a list of the missing required packages:

> ```
>    Installing requirements for osx/10.8/x86_64, might require sudo password
>    Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
> -> Missing required packages: libtool, libxml2, libxslt, sqlite.
>    Skipping update of certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem'.
> ```

- I "homebrewed" those packages:

  `$ brew update`

  `$ brew install libtool libxml2 libxslt sqlite`

*You can recheck the requirements by running the `rvm requirements run` command again to see you're clear of missing packages.*

- Reinstall ruby, in my case 1.9.3-p392:

  `$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p392`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks!, I will try to follow those steps if I have to reinstall or when I upgrade to OSX 10.8.

Comment: The problem is probably with openssl-1.0.1. Seems like ruby is intended to be built against openssl-0.9.x.

I encountered the same error building ruby-2.0.0. Here's my workaround: https://gist.github.com/timcharper/5778185

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this one too. Try following the steps [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130309044343/http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html).

Basically, on the Terminal:

> You can also install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and try this:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install openssl
$ brew link openssl --force
$ brew install curl-ca-bundle
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to update openssl with brew's steps but when I run 'openssl version' I still get the oldest version that points to /usr/bin/openssl.

Comment: Ok, then you might need to change your PATH variable to point to the Cellar directory before searching /usr/bin.

Comment: I finally ended up installing without  `--with-openssh-dir=$rvm_path/usr` line. So far it works.