# rvm installing ruby 1.8.4 openssl issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rvm

I am trying to install ruby 1.8.4 and rails 2.3.2 on mac osx. This is what is available on hosting I have purchased. I am facing couple of issues related to installation. I was trying to install ruby 1.8.4 using rvm. When I try to use below command:

```
rvm install 1.8.4
```

I get below error:

> openssl_missing.h:68: error: conflicting types for 'HMAC_CTX_copy' /opt/local/include/openssl/hmac.h:102: error: previous declaration of 'HMAC_CTX_copy' was here openssl_missing.h:92: error: conflicting types for 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy' /opt/local/include/openssl/evp.h:502: error: previous declaration of 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy' was here make[1]: *** [ossl_cipher.o] Error 1

So I started searching a week ago. Tried almost everything. Here are few links I have already tried:

[Ruby and "You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your Gemfile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212104/ruby-openssl-issues-on-mac)

[RVM ruby on rails issue OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021208/rvm-ruby-on-rails-issue-openssl)

[Openssl error message on install log when installing ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OSX 10.6.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504774/openssl-error-message-on-install-log-when-installing-ruby-1-9-3-on-mac-osx-10-6)

[Error running 'make -j2' when running rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383853/error-running-make-j2-when-running-rvm-install-ruby-2-0-0-p247)

I was able to install ruby using below command:

```
rvm install 1.8.4 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/local
```

but when I tried rvm list. It was saying broken next to 1.8.4. After that I was not able to install rails.

I saw some posts on github that says that ruby installation requires openssl version 0.9.8. But when I try installing openssl using below command:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

It installs openssl 1.0.1.

Few things want to make clear:

I had installed macports initially and then I had installed homebrew as well. which may be conflicting. But I am expecting they are not. But just to try I tried removing macports and reinstalling rvm. But when I tried below command :

```
rvm install 1.8.4
```

rvm installed macports for me. Not sure why.

Can anybody suggest me what I am missing here or may be I am doing it completely in a wrong way?

Comment: Given so many good options for Rails hosting, perhaps you'd be better off finding a service that lets you deploy with Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0? Heroku is popular. Cloud66 is an alternative. Earlier versions of Rails are known to have significant security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But I have already paid for that hosting. So was thinking if I can go with that.

Comment: @webdev +1 for a good question. Since you have to install ruby by yourself why the 1.8.4 version? It seems illogical to say that your provider only alows 1.8.4 when you have to build it by yourself.

Comment: sorry may be I was not clear. I am installing ruby on my local machine for development. Once done I will move code to hosting server.

Answer (score 1):

All ruby `1.8.*` series is no more supported, you should drop the hosting that provides unsupported ruby version and request refund.

The currently supported ruby versions (as for today) are:

- `1.9.3`
- `2.0.0`

They both are mostly compatible (noticable exception is default `UTF8` encoding in `2.0.0`).

If you use RVM then you can use latest stable ruby release with this two commands:

```
rvm get stable # update RVM
rvm use ruby --install --default
```

the `--install` will install ruby if missing, and the `--default` will set it as default for new shell sessions.

Comment: Thanks I have cancelled it. Can you suggest me what's best hosting for ruby on rails?

Comment: that's a separate question - but as it would be opinion based it is not fit for SO, start from http://rubyonrails.org/community, a good think would be http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk

Comment: And if you are working against SketchUp which embeds Ruby 1.8? Then how do you solve this?

Comment: @thomthom - open new question and provide more details, give some links describing what is it you are doing and full error output.